# Magento custom module how to update database script

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.8

I have created update script for my magento module but when I reinstall my module my update script is not running I have all steps properly updated my config.xml file with latest version and rename my update script name to but still nothing works[my file structure is define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A12z.jpg)

Comment: (http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/),(http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54) and (kamleshkamble.blogspot.in/2013/02/custom-module-in-magento-with-custom.html)

Comment: Maybe you getting an error in the update script? Did you checked logs?

Comment: nothing is generating in error logs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it  by updating version in config.xml and create mysql upgrade php file in module's sql folder